# How do I sort a multi-dimensional array returned by WP Rest API?

Tags: php, wordpress

Using WordPress REST API, I'm externally getting posts:
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?orderby=date&order=desc&per_page=12

Body results:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2022-05-05T12:12:12",
        "link": "https://example.com/blog/132/",
        "title": {
            "rendered": "F: Title"
        }
    },
    {
        "date": "2022-04-04T12:12:12",
        "link": "https://example.com/blog/434/",
        "title": {
            "rendered": "E: Title"
        }
    },
    {
        "date": "2022-03-03T12:12:12",
        "link": "https://example.com/blog/324/",
        "title": {
            "rendered": "A: Title"
        }
    },
    etc...

]
```

I'd like to sort title by alphabetical order.

What would be the best solution?

I'm unable to use WP_Query since the posts are being pulled from an external WP API source.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153737/sort-json-array-by-value-using-php

Comment: @AmiraliAmirifar Thanks for this, unfortunately it didn't work for me

Comment: This is a json response. So it's an array of json objects. Where and in what language do you want to sort this? Is the client calling the api a php-client or is it some frontend js-client?

Comment: @Christoffer I'd like to sort this in PHP and the client calling the API is also PHP. The thing with WordPress Rest API, I can set order by using GET parameters. But I need to get the latest posts in DESC order AND by alphabetical order. This would have been super easy using WP_Query, but it's not possible when calling an API endpoint from an external source. 
Currently, I'm able to get the latest posts in DESC order in JSON. Now I'd like to sort the titles by alphabetical order using PHP and then foreach loop and print as HTML.

Comment: If you want multiple sorting rules, then write arrays of value on both sides of the spaceship operator [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59175345/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something like that :

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['title']['rendered'] == $b['title']['rendered']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['title']['rendered'] < $b['title']['rendered']) ? -1 : 1;
}

$ar = json_decode($yourJson, TRUE);
usort($ar, "cmp");

...

?>
```

Comment: This function worked fine until I passed the newly sorted array in a foreach loop. The data in each array somehow is not printing correctly.

Comment: It is not the answerer's fault if you have not clearly presented your scenario.

Comment: @svgta thank you for this. I discovered that when json_decode associative is set to true, I had to change from object operator to array.
For instance, I changed this $post->title->rendered to $post['title']['rendered'] and all worked out!

Answer (score 0):

use this function to sort any array

```
function array_sort($array, $on, $order = SORT_ASC)
{
    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();

    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }
        switch ($order) {
            case SORT_ASC:
                asort($sortable_array);
                break;
            case SORT_DESC:
                arsort($sortable_array);
                break;
        }


        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}
```

Comment: Wow, whatever this unexplained script is doing, it definitely looks over-engineered /convoluted.